# How to restore normal boot process after pacman update on EFI?

Tags: arch-linux, boot, systemd, uefi

I just updated my system and upon reboot I've found myself in emergency mode. This is a `dm-crypt+LUKS` `EFI` system (thinkpad) using `gummiboot`. `journalctl -xb` reports that `/boot` could not be mounted. Following this [thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=171880), I tried downgrading my kernel to `3.18.2` using `pacman -U`, and while it did downgrade, I still can't boot normally.

Thinking the kernel upgrade process just caught a glitch, I tried re-updating my kernel (from `/var/cache/pacman/pkg/`, but that didn't affect the next boot. `mkinitcpio` gave a warning that the boot partition wasn't mounted.

The line currently in my `/etc/fstab` is:

```
LABEL=EFI /boot vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,code page=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,short name=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 2
```

`uname -r` tells me the emergency mode is using Linux kernel `3.18.2` instead of the `3.18.6` kernel I updated to. `pacman -Q` says Linux `3.18.6-1`.

`Journalctl -xb | grep -I failed | less` shows that systemd failed to load display manager and failed to start Load Kernel Modules. Two units failed according to `systemctl --state=failed`.

When I startup and when I try and connect to the internet with netctl, I get the `codepage cp437` error and am prompted again for my root password. Further investigation reveals that this is the MS-DOS/FAT extended ASCII encoding specified for my EFI partition in `/etc/fstab`. If this is just a misalignment between `/boot` and `/`, how could I resync them past `pacman -U`?

I'd really appreciate suggestions for restoring my system. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Chroot in, make sure  that `/boot` is mounted and `pacman -Syu && mkinitcpio -p linux`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jasonwryan` pointed me in the right direction.

I performed the following steps:

1) downloaded latest installation media and made a bootable USB

2) unencrypted my LUKS LVM volumes

3) mounted my volume to the live USB file system in `/mnt/arch`, a directory I created (including `/mnt/arch/boot`, and `/mnt/arch/home`)

4) connected to the internet with `wifi-menu`

5) used `arch-chroot` to change root

6) updated with pacman

7) rebooted